# ARM Assembly register return to initial state

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm getting an error - Segmentation fault (error 139), when I try to run my assembly program. As I understand it's because I use registers above r3, and don't return them to initial state. How can I do that?

Below is my code, what could be the issue?

```
.text
.align  2
    .global matmul
    .type   matmul, %function
    matmul:
    @-- check if matrices can be multiplied
    cmp r1,r3
    beq  loadvalues @-- matrices can be multiplied
    mov r0,#1
    bx lr

@-- load matrice values
loadvalues:
    stmdb SP!, { r4-r15 }
    ldr r4, [sp, #0]
    ldr r5, [sp, #4]
    ldr r6, [sp, #8]
    mov r7, #0
    mov r8, #0
    mov r9, #0
    mov r10, #4
    b firstloop     
    mov r0, #0
    bx lr

@-- Loop r7 to r0
firstloop:
    cmp r7, r0
    blt firstloopex
firstloopex:
    add r7, r7, #1
    b secondloop
    LDMIA SP!, { r4-r15 }
endfirstloop:
    mov r0, #0
    bx lr   

@-- Loop r8 to r4
secondloop:
    cmp r8, r4
    blt secondloopex
secondloopex:
    add r8, r8, #1
    b thirdloop
endsecondloop:
    mul r11, r7, r8
    mul r11, r10, r11
    sub r11, r11, r10
    str r0, [r6, r11]
    mov r8, #0

@-- Loop r9 to r1
thirdloop:
    cmp r9, r1
    blt thirdloopex
thirdloopex:
    add r9, r9, #1
    @-- load value of matrice 1
    mul r11, r7, r9
    mul r11, r10, r11
    sub r11, r11, r10
    ldr r12, [r2, r11]
    @-- load value of matrice 2
    mul r11, r9, r8
    mul r11, r10, r11
    sub r11, r11, r10
    ldr r13, [r5, r11]
    @-- sum up value
    mul r14, r12, r13
    add r0, r0, r14
endthirdloop:
    mov r9, #0
```

Comment: `push` the register before modifying it, `pop` it before returning?

Comment: It looks like you are preserving callee-saved registers (or at least trying to) already. However, `LDMIA SP!, { r4-r15 }` and `ldr r13, [r5, r11]` particularly stand out - try single-stepping through those in a debugger (if you reach them at all) and seeing what happens afterwards. Then go and look up what roles `r13` and `r15` serve... ;)

Comment: You appear to have fallen for ARM's propaganda about the architecture having a large general-purpose register file. It does not. Also, read the architecture reference manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ARM, you need to save and restore {r4-r11}. Past that are all special registers. Following is a skeleton of a function in ARM.

```
my_func:
    push {r4-r11}    # Save callee-saved registers. stmdb sp!, {r4-r11}
    ...
    pop  {r4-r11}    # Restore callee-saved registers. ldmia sp!, {r4-r11}
    mov r0, #0       # Save return value to r0
    bx lr
```

Note: Sometimes r9 is a special register too and should not be save-restored. I won't go into details because its rare enough. You can read about it in the AAPCS (Arm Architecture Procedure Call Standard) http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf.